# Replacing div class in SharePoint using JQuery1.4min in Content Editor

Tags: jquery

Very new on how JQuery works and trying to replace the class name of a summary links div tag.

```
<div class="slm-layout-main groupmarker">sometext</div>
```

want to change that to

```
<div class="slm-layout-main groupmarker ms-rteFontSize-3">sometext</div>
```

and there are multiple places for this diz tag to be replaced.

I tried in the ContentEditor something like this:

```
<script src="/sites/lrp/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

$(".slm-layout-main groupmarker")
.removeClass("slm-layout-main groupmarker")
.addClass("slm-layout-main groupmarker ms-rteFontSize-3");
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you are removing the classes and then re-adding them?

Comment: Working with summary links inside Sharepoint and the request is to change the font size.

Answer (score 1):

This will get all elements with `.slm-layout-main` and for each one that also has `.groupmaker` it will add `.ms-rteFontSize-3`. This *doesn't deal* with the case where other classes are present.

```
$(".slm-layout-main").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass(".groupmaker")){
    $(this).addClass"ms-rteFontSize-3");
  }
});
```

Comment: My script editor now looks like:
<script src="/sites/lrp/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

$(".slm-layout-main").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass(".groupmaker")){
    $(this).addClass"ms-rteFontSize-3");
  }
});

script></script>

And I get the Webpage error details
Message: Expected ';'
Line: 732
Char: 21

Answer (score 1):

Your selector isn't quite what you think it is. Think of this as if it were a css class you were defining and you would end up looking for `.slm-layout-main`'s that contain elements called `<groupmarker>`

```
$(".slm-layout-main groupmarker")
```

Should be -

```
$(".slm-layout-main.groupmarker")
```

**Edit**
After re-reading your application you will still need to iterate over your selection:

```
$(".slm-layout-main.groupmarker").each(function(){
   $(this)
      .removeClass("slm-layout-main groupmarker")
      .addClass("slm-layout-main groupmarker ms-rteFontSize-3");
});
```

Comment: I have spent quite a bit of time slogging through the SharePoint mud, crazy selector tricks have become my forte :D

Comment: My script editor now looks like:
<script src="/sites/lrp/Shared%20Documents/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

$(".slm-layout-main.groupmarker").each(function(){
   $(this)
      .removeClass("slm-layout-main groupmarker")
      .addClass("slm-layout-main groupmarker ms-rteFontSize-3");
});

script></script>

And I get the Webpage error details
Message: Syntax Error
Line: 739
Char: 8

Comment: Post what is on that line and also test that blurb that I posted in my answer in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools and see if it executes properly. This will tell you if jQuery is loaded properly etc.